# Finding order of permutations using disjoint cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Find the order of $t^{1000}$ where the permutation is (I have converted it to disjoint cycles), $(1 3 8)(2 7)(4 9 6 5)$.

I know the order is the LCM of the lengths of the disjoint cycles so for $t$ alone I found the order to be $12$.

I am not too sure how to do this for $t^{1000}$. Would I have to just raise ${12}^{1000}$ or am I missing a step completely?

Comment: You know that $t$ has order 12. That means that $t^{12} = 1$ (the identity). Then $t^{1000} = t^{988}$. Do you see how to proceed?

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter oh...so I would have to break down the exponent to use the 12 I have that gives me 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the order is $12$ says that $t^{12}$ is the identity, as is any power of $t$ that is a multiple of $12$.  Then $t^{1000}=t^{1000 \mod 12}=t^4$.  What power do you need to raise $t^4$ to to get the identity?

Comment: you would have to raise it to the third power

Comment: That is right.   $(t^{1000})^3$ is the identity, so the order of $t^{1000}$ is $3$.  Because $1000$ is a multiple of $4$, the cycles of length $2$ and $4$ are already back at the start, so they don't contribute to the order of $t^{1000}4

Comment: I am a bit confused. So once I have that the order of t is 12 why did you use it as mod in the power for t^1000?

Comment: Because you found $t^{12}=1$, so $(t^{12})^n=t^{12n}=1$ for any $n$.  This tells us the powers of $t$ are isomorphic to the cyclic group of order $12$.  We keep going around and around and all we care about is the partial cycle left over at the end.

Comment: This would not be so easy if the power was $1001$ instead.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, if $g \in G$ has order $n$, then $g^k$ has order $n/\gcd(n,k)$.

Thus, $t^{1000}$ has order $12/\gcd(12,1000)=3$.